# Django : Run Django at system boot

Tags: django, linux, ubuntu, cron

Basically i am Django developer so i have just working knowledge in Linux

I have a django app running on `EC2` .

Now here is the problem suppose if i am restarting the ec2  my django app need to be run again .I don't want to run the django server again and again .

So i tried to put this process in cronjob like

```
@reboot cd /path/to/dir/./manage.py runserver
```

Unfortunately it is not working .What might problem is here ?

Please tell me the way to run Django application at system booting .

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using runserver to serve your application in production. You should use a real webserver, for example Apache. That will automatically start up on reboot.

Comment: <Location "/home/vk/Desktop/django/class2go">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE class2go.settings
    PythonOption django.root /class2go
    PythonDebug On
</Location>
 getting error (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down

Comment: This is scary. I can't imagine how many people manage to use runserver for production...